# Embed a map generated with mymaps

Tags: api, mymaps

I need to embed a map generated with mymaps in a site that will have many views. Is it necessary to have an API to be able to share the map without visualization limits?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this this way:

```
<script>
    var x = 0;
    function initialize() {
        
          var map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById("map"), {
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          });

          var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
              url: "http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=key from integrate on my website i mymaps",
              map: map
          });
```

Is this what you searched for?

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.